# increase height on fixed div and make scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have a main div called `.div1` on top of it I have a fixed div container that contains my fixed div called `.fixedDiv`. What I'm trying to do is increase the height of class `.fixedDiv` and make the scroll respond to the height and content of `.fixedDiv` and not class `.div1`. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 275vh;
  background-color: gold;
}

.fixedDivCon {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(43, 45, 46, 0.89);
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fixedDivCon .fixedDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  /*not working*/
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixedDivCon">
  <div class="fixedDiv">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div1">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 275vh;
  background-color: gold;
}

.fixedDivCon {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Enter desired height here */
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: rgba(43, 45, 46, 0.89);
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fixedDivCon .fixedDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 1) I wanted ```.fixedDivCon``` to cover the whole body with certain transparency set to it. If i use your method the whole body won't be covered. 2) If i set the height of ```.fixedDivCon``` to like 200vh the container will have that height but half of it wont be in view and when you scroll the background content is getting scrolled not ```.fixedDivCon```